# PHP: Is it programatically possible to append iterator value to array key name in loop?

Tags: php, iterator, multidimensional-array, key, append

I have a multidimensional array object, and in a loop I would like to append an iterator to the key and obtain the value.  Sample code for demonstration:

```
    $array_object->example1 = 1;
    $array_object->example2 = 2;


$i = 1;

while ($i <= 2) {

       echo ($array_object->example . $i); //this does not work
       //how to accomplish same?
       $i++
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) will solve your problem, immediately:

```
$example = "example" . $i;
echo $array_object->$example;
```

But you may want to consider making `$array_object->example` an array, and accessing it like:

```
echo $array_object->example[$i];
```

Answer (score 9):

`echo $array_object->{'example' . $i};`

Answer (score 2):

```
$n = "example" . $i;

echo $array_object->$n;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to set up the variable first, before using the -> operator...

```
while ($i <= 2) {
        $property = 'example' . $i;  // or "example$i", whichever you prefer
        echo ($array_object->$property);
        $i++
    }
```

EDIT: damn I'm slow replying...